# Linq to SQL - SubmitChanges() - Check if insert was successful

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code -

```
public bool InsertUser(params) 
{
    User objUser = new User(params);
    objDataContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(objUser);
    objDataContext.SubmitChanges();
    return objUser.Id >= 0;
}
```

Calling method -

```
if (!_database.InsertUser(params))
{
    //WriteErrorMessage 
}
```

As I understand from various posts that if we want to know whether an insert was successful or not, we should check if any exception is being thrown.

However above code is relying on whether newly inserted Id is >=0 or not.

Can please guide -

- If I should change above code and add a try-catch instead?
- Is there any possible scenario where no error is thrown by SubmitChanges() but newly inserted Id <= 0 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I should change above code and add a try-catch instead?

No, don't do that as in that case you will not be able to get the exact reason of failure. If you catch it then the information of failure will be lost and will not propogate to the user.

However if you think that giving exception to the user is not a good idea and you need to catch it then simply place it inside the try catch like this:

```
public bool SubmitChanges()
{
  try{
     //your code
     db.SubmitChanges();
     return true;
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    // some code to catch exception
    return false;
  }
}
```

> Is there any possible scenario where no error is thrown by SubmitChanges() but newly inserted Id <= 0 ?

If you are getting the value >=0, then there is no point to worry about this.

You can also use the [GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) like this:

> Gets the modified objects tracked by DataContext.

```
ChangeSet cs = db.GetChangeSet();
Console.Write("Changes: {0}", cs);
```

Comment: I disagree with not catching the exception and think your logic is flawed. There are many valid reasons to catch it - you can format the exception, add in some logic to recover from the exception, or in this case find out the exact field that caused the `DBValidationException`. Showing a raw exception to a user will often do nothing except confuse them. If you really are worried about losing the exception, you can always just `throw` it.

Comment: @user1666620:- Updated my answer to add the try catch option as well.

Answer (score 1):

if your code execute the line  `objDataContext.SubmitChanges();` and comes on `return objUser.Id >= 0;` your insert will be successfull. you don't need to worry after that. let sql server and your compiler take care of the rest

Yes can use try catch to efficiently catch the error and display appropriate messages.