# Unit of Work patterns making sure data is saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the Unit of Work patterns and want to a value back from the database to make sure it has updated the database successfully. Is there a way to do that?

```
UnitOfWork.Save();

public void Save()
{
    try
    {                
        Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception dbEx)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(
            string.Format(
                "Exception caught while saving unit of work: {0}", dbEx.StackTrace
                ));

        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`SubmitChanges()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-submit-changes-to-the-database), a transaction is created.

> All objects that have pending changes are ordered into a sequence of objects based on the dependencies between them. Objects whose changes depend on other objects are sequenced after their dependencies.
>
> Immediately before any actual changes are transmitted, LINQ to SQL starts a transaction to encapsulate the series of individual commands.

Using the default conflict resolution mode ([`FailOnFirstConflict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.conflictmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_ConflictMode_FailOnFirstConflict)), the entirety of your changes fail to save when an error occurs in any one of them because the transaction encapsulating all your changes is rolled back.

**That means that if your submission succeeds, you can be sure your unit of work was completed.** You do not need to get a value back to determine whether or not your changes were saved.

---

You could also set the conflict resolution mode to [`ContinueOnConflict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.conflictmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_ConflictMode_ContinueOnConflict) if you have changes that you know do not depend on each other and you want all changes to be attempted even if one or more fail.

```cs
Context.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
```

Comment: If I want to use the default resolution mode is there a way to know if the changes failed and it was rolled back?

Comment: `SubmitChanges()` throws an error if the conflict resolution mode is `FailOnFirstConflict` and a conflict is encountered. If you don't catch an error, you can assume the changes succeeded. [Here's another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789466/linq-to-sql-submitchanges-check-if-insert-was-successful).